# How to write string based dynamic function dispatch in python from within a class?

Tags: python, dispatch

I want to dynamically determine function dispatch in my python code.
Like so :
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-use-strings-to-call-functions-methods

I build a dispatch dictionary wherein:
`dispatch = {'foo' : foo_function, 'bar': bar:function}`

And then from within code, I can call the appropriate function based on my `data` string by saying:
`dispatch[data]()`

So far so good. My issue is I want this functionality inside a class accessible to it's methods:

```
class Demo(object):
    """ Demonstrate the issue
    """

    dispatch = {'foo' : self.call_foo, 'bar': self.call_bar}

    def parse_component(self, data, some_param):
        self.__class__.dispatch[data](self, some_param)

    def call_foo(self, some_param):
        """ Do some intelligent work here"""
        pass

    def call_bar(self, some_param):
        """ Do some intelligent work here"""
        pass
```

The problem is that dispatch table is a class variable and does not have a notion of the instance methods self.call_foo and self.call_bar.
I tried using get_attr :

```
class Demo(object):
     dispatch = {'foo': getattr(Demo, 'call_foo')}
```

I get a NameError on Demo with this. It does not recognize the class name from within the class which I guess makes sense.

Other than making dispatch another instance method, is there any other way to do this?
Ideally dispatch should be a class variable/method since it is constant to the class.

Comment: Just ditch the `self`---it'll refer to it as a function rather than a bound method, so you'll 
need to explicitly pass in `self` which you are already doing anyways when you dispatch. The dict needs to be defined after the methods, so that those names (`call_foo`, `call_bar`) exist.

Comment: you were already so close!

Comment: To the poster: would you mind answering your own question, or @alkasm would you kindly provide the answer as an actual answer with the correct working example?

Comment: @Otheus sure, I gave it an answer! Good to call me out on it :)

Answer (score 0):

The functions `Demo.call_foo` and `Demo.call_bar` are functions which take in an instance `self` and `some_param`. When you create an instance of `Demo`, e.g. `d = Demo()`, those functions now become *bound methods* where the `self` parameter is already passed for you. But the other form still exists, so you can call instance methods with `ClassName.method(instance, ...)`. For example:

```py
class Demo:
    def call_foo(self):
        print("called foo")
```

Calling it both ways works:

```py
>>> d = Demo()
>>> Demo.call_foo(d)
called foo
>>> d.call_foo()
called foo
```

This is relevant to your question because inside the class definition, you don't have an instance `self` to use, but you *can* refer to the functions directly. Since they are functions defined in the class scope, they can be referenced directly like any other class attribute.

But like we've seen above, you can pass the instance along to the function. You're already doing that in `parse_component`. So the only problem with your current code is that you tried to use `self` to reference the methods. But since the dict is defined in the class scope, you can just refer to them by name:

```py
class Demo:
    
    def parse_component(self, data, some_param):
        self.__class__.dispatch[data](self, some_param)

    def call_foo(self, some_param):
        print("called foo with", some_param)

    def call_bar(self, some_param):
        print("called bar with", some_param)

    dispatch = {'foo' : call_foo, 'bar': call_bar}
```

And using it:

```py
>>> d = Demo()
>>> d.parse_component("foo", 2)
called foo with 2
>>> d.parse_component("bar", 3)
called bar with 3
>>> Demo.parse_component(d, "foo", 4)
called foo with 4
```